# Trouble understanding why CSS won't copy from static HTML page to Flask

Tags: html, css, flask

Having to make a market tool for second hand PC components with Flask. Part of this task involved first displaying static html pages with placeholder data, and then converting to flask, simple enough (I already knew Flask), or so I thought.

Now I'm having issues where not all of the .css file will apply when I use a base.html template, which stores my navbar, footer and obviously my heading/metadata components.

[Here's the Static HTML home page heading, where you can see a nicely formatted sidebar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkkcT.jpg)

[Here's the footer on the same page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPQc4.png)

Now when I load the template up in Flask, it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gW6TR.jpg) at the top of the page, and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dIvh.png) at the footer. As you can see, only part of the css has applied.

In terms of the side-bar, its all contained inside a division called side-bar. The side-bar ul, side-bar ul li components are applying, but the overall side-bar div refuses to apply. The footer is also not formatting full stop. The stylesheet is only called in base.html, not in index.html. Im doing so by using

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static',filename='styles/base.css') }}">
```

My folder structure is fine

---bench ---

------static---

---------styles---

------------base.css---

Bootstrap components work fine

Comment: Possibly cache problems? Try to perform a hard refresh in your browser, or clear your browser cache.

Comment: First thing I did, done it with several browsers too. I even confirmed modification by changing the colour.